# How to add dotted line on a view on appcelerator titanium?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy, tss

I know we can't add dotted to border style on .tss. May I know any hacks or idea to add dotted line on the border for a view?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create an image [image: Dot image]

You can use MaskedImage and set the color you want

```
<MaskedImage id="dotted" tint="#68BCBF" mask="/images/dottedTuto.png" width="Ti.UI.FILL" height="Ti.UI.FILL"></MaskedImage>
```